# I'm getting a 404 on a user/reset/%/%/% path

Tags: users

I'm getting a 404 on a user/reset/%/%/% path. The cached router item looks good but the page is still not found.

```
Array
(
[title] => Reset password
[page callback] => drupal_get_form
[page arguments] => Array
    (
        [0] => user_pass_reset
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )

[access callback] => 1
[type] => 0
[file] => user.pages.inc
[module] => user
[_load_functions] => Array
    (
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
    )

[to_arg_functions] => 
[weight] => 0
[_number_parts] => 5
[_parts] => Array
    (
        [0] => user
        [1] => reset
        [2] => %
        [3] => %
        [4] => %
    )

[_fit] => 24
[_visible] => 
[_tab] => 
[tab_parent] => 
[tab_root] => user/reset/%/%/%
[menu_name] => user-menu
[delivery callback] => 
[theme callback] => 
[theme arguments] => Array
    (
    )

[load_functions] => a:3:{i:2;N;i:3;N;i:4;N;}
[access arguments] => Array
    (
    )

[title arguments] => Array
    (
    )

[title callback] => t
[description] => 
[position] => 
[context] => 0
[path] => user/reset/%/%/%
[file path] => 
[include file] => modules/user/user.pages.inc
)
```

I've used drush fn-hook menu_alter to see if anything is changing this path but I would figure that end up in the cached router entry above. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL being requested when you get the 404?

Comment: Something like this (changed a few things)... http://myclient.jimstamper.com/user/reset/107/1443120393/abcABCeF6sQPF15U1JSw5y9b3k0neXSFZW7RE9yG9A

Comment: To clarify, that link is getting a 404 because it doesn't exist. My 404 error is actually kicked back by drupal.

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by a third party custom module, funny enough *not* in hook_menu_alter.